# Android - ARToolkit - 2D Image instead a cube

Tags: android, artoolkit

I'm trying to display simple 2d image on my marker. I found solution how to create a cube on marker.

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {

gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Apply the ARToolKit projection matrix
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadMatrixf(ARToolKit.getInstance().getProjectionMatrix(), 0);

gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);        
gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

// If the marker is visible, apply its transformation, and draw a cube
if (ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerVisible(markerID)) {
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadMatrixf(ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerTransformation(markerID), 0);
    cube.draw(gl);
}
```

How can I change above code to achieve expected result?